# python How to turn a double dictionary into a tab delimited file

Tags: python

```
dict = {a : {aa:1, bb:2, cc:3}, b: {aa:1, bb:2, cc:3}}
```

I want to turn this dictionary into a tab delimited file like this:

```
       aa  bb  cc
   a   1   2   3
   b   1   2   3
```

How should I do this. Thanks

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(d).T`.. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

The following will work

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(dict).T.to_csv('sample.tsv', sep='\t')
```